# Why I have a bug while making owl carousel reinit on block resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

I use owl carousel 2 for sliders.
Responsive works fine on window resize, but I need to make carousel resize while changing block-container width. (Container width changes when opening sidebar.)

[This is how it looks when sidebar is closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWXdq.png)

[And this when sidebar is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV5Tm.png)

I've tried using **responsiveBaseElement**:

```js
// Initialize news slider
var $owl = $("#news-list").owlCarousel({
    dots: false,
    nav: true,
    navText: false,
    loop: true,
    responsiveBaseElement: ".box-to-check",
    responsive : {
      0: {
          items: 1
      },
      480: {
          items: 2
      },
      768: {
          items: 3
      }
    }
});
```

Also I've tried using `refresh.owl.carousel`:

```js
$owl.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
```

Then I've found out that there is a bug in refreshing owl carousel and I've tried to destroy it completely and build once more:

```js
$owl.trigger('destroy.owl.carousel').removeClass('owl-carousel owl-loaded');
$owl.find('.owl-stage-outer').children().unwrap();

$owl.owlCarousel({
  dots: false,
  nav: true,
  navText: false,
  loop: true,
  responsiveBaseElement: ".box-to-check",
  responsive : {
    0: {
        items: 1
    },
    480: {
        items: 2
    },
    768: {
        items: 3
    }
  }
});
```

And partially it worked. But it adjusts to a new width when I close sidebar.
(I mean I have to open sidebar (BONUS/ACCENT buttons on top left) and then to close it reinit slider.)
You can see live example here - ttomoday(dot)github(dot)io/v/upc/